# Can I use my Apple Watch 4, having only an iPhone 8 Plus? If not, what is the latest Apple Watch that will pair with my phone?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I have an iPhone 8 Plus, and in continuing attempts to pair it with an Apple Watch 4, was able to read the iPhone just barely display a dialog saying “iPhone is out of date,” quick as a flash, and then quickly slide it down.

Can I get my Apple Watch working without buying a newer iPhone?

If not, what is the latest generation Apple Watch that I can use without buying a newer iPhone?

Comment: What is the version of iOS running on your iPhone 8 Plus? What about Apple Watch 4?

Answer (score 2):

Your iPhone can work with *any* Apple Watch starting from the original one to the latest one. The only thing that needs to be ensured is that both the iPhone and Apple Watch are running the *compatible* versions of iOS and watchOS.

It's recommended that the devices run the latest available version of the respective OS. Currently the latest version of iOS available for iPhone 8 Plus is iOS 13.2, while the one for Apple Watch Series 4 is watchOS 6.0.1.

To answer your questions specifically:

> Can I use my Apple Watch 4, having only an iPhone 8 Plus?

Yes.

> If not, what is the latest Apple Watch that will pair with my phone?

As stated above, you can pair technically pair *any* Apple Watch with iPhone 8 Plus.

> Can I get my Apple Watch working without buying a newer iPhone?

Yes.

> If not, what is the latest generation Apple Watch that I can use without buying a newer iPhone?

Apple Watch Series 5, which is the latest model released by Apple.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve tried to pair it with a few permutations after updating iOS to 13.2, and every time it says “Pairing failed.” This includes manual pairing. Advice? Should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @ChristosHayward What about watchOS? Have you updated it to 6.0?

Comment: After multiple attempts and permutations, I now have what seems to be a working watch. I don’t remember a rougher on boarding UX with an Apple product.